# How to make Highcharts ticks distributed evenly no matter what the tick values are

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, bar-chart, react-highcharts

I created a bar chart with some chart options with Highcharts React

https://codesandbox.io/s/highchart-bar-uneven-ticks-c6mi5p

The ticks are not distributed evenly. Is there any way to make them even regardless of their values?

[image]

I expect to find an option from Highcharts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can translate your tick positions into a constant interval, calculate data based on the proportion and show mocked labels/tooltips.

For example:

```
const tickPositions = [40, 60, 80, 100, 160, 220, 280, 340, 400, 460, 520];
// [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
const processedTickPositions = tickPositions.map((tick, index) => index);

const getProcessedData = (data) => {
  const foundTick = tickPositions.find(tick => tick > data);
  const prevTickIndex = tickPositions.indexOf(foundTick) - 1;
  const prevTick = tickPositions[prevTickIndex];

  if (!foundTick) {
    return processedTickPositions[0];
  }

  return prevTickIndex + (data - prevTick) / (foundTick - prevTick);
}

const chartOptions = {
  series: [{
    ...,
    data: [{
      y: getProcessedData(180),
      custom: {
        value: 180,
        unit: "kg",
        label: "label"
      }
    }]
  }],
  yAxis: [{
    ...,
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        return tickPositions[this.pos]
      }
    }
  }],
  ...
};

Highcharts.chart('container', chartOptions);
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yj7akt29/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.labels.formatter

Comment: Thanks,
Your solution works brilliantly in React, but the formatter callback would not work with highcharts-export-server when I want to send chart options as JSON to the server. Is there any alternative option that I could use in this case?

Comment: Hi @Van Nguyen, Unfortunately, I don't see any alternative. It is some kind of workaround and we need to use the formatter function to mock labels.